# Dynamic query execution error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to execute the following dynamic query code:

```
  declare @sql nvarchar(max)
  set @sql = 'DECLARE @DatePartitionFunction nvarchar(max) = N''CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION DatePartitionFunction (datetime) 
                                             AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('';
    DECLARE @incremental_date nvarchar(150);

    select @incremental_date = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),112)+'
    declare @counter int = 0;
    WHILE @counter < 3
    BEGIN
        SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),DATEADD(DD, @counter, @incremental_date),112) + '''' + N'', '';
        SET @counter += 1; 
    END

    SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),DATEADD(DD, @counter, @incremental_date),112)  + '''' + N'');'';
    print (@DatePartitionFunction)
    end;'

exec (@sql);
```

However, it returns an error stating incorrect syntax.

When I execute the same code outside the dynamic query context, it returns output. Stated below is the same code outside the dynamic query context

```
        DECLARE @DatePartitionFunction nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION DatePartitionFunction (datetime) 
                                                         AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (';
        DECLARE @incremental_date nvarchar(150);

        select @incremental_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),112)
        declare @counter int = 0;
        WHILE @counter < 3
        BEGIN
            SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),DATEADD(DD, @counter, @incremental_date),112) + '''' + N', ';
            SET @counter += 1; 
            END

        SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),DATEADD(DD, @counter, @incremental_date),112)  + '''' + N');';
        print (@DatePartitionFunction);
```

It produces the desired output text as imparted below:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION DatePartitionFunction (datetime) 
 AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('20150923', '20150924', '20150925', '20150926');
```

This is what i want the console to output in case of the aforementioned dynamic query, however I'm being met with errors.
Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The error you are receiving is because you have a trailing `end;` in your dynamic SQL version that is out of place (and doesn't exist in the non-dynamic version that works):

   ```
   end;' --> should be just '
   ```
2. Your dynamic SQL version is missing the required number of single quotes (so when you fix 1., you'll still have dates that look like integers).
3. This seems like a tidier approach, mostly because it avoids a lot of the single-quote-spaghetti, looping constructs, repetitive conversions, and changing the number of partitions requires only one change in the `TOP()` argument:

   ```
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION   
      DatePartitionFunction (datetime)
      AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (';  
   ;WITH c(rn) AS 
   (
     SELECT TOP (4) CHAR(39) + 
       CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)-1, 
       GETDATE()), 112)  + CHAR(39)
     FROM sys.all_columns
   )
   SELECT @sql += STUFF((SELECT ',' + rn FROM c 
     ORDER BY rn FOR XML PATH, 
     TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'varchar(max)'),1,1,'');
   SET @sql += N');';

   PRINT @sql;
   ```

   Why you would then need to nest that in dynamic SQL, I'm not sure, but you could:

   ```
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
      DECLARE @pf NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION   
      DatePartitionFunction (datetime)  
      AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('';

   ;WITH c(rn) AS 
   (
     SELECT TOP (4) CHAR(39) + 
       CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)-1, 
       GETDATE()), 112)  + CHAR(39)
     FROM sys.all_columns
   )
   SELECT @pf += STUFF((SELECT '','' + rn FROM c 
     ORDER BY rn FOR XML PATH, 
     TYPE).value(N''.[1]'',N''varchar(max)''),1,1,'''');
   SET @pf += N'');'';

   PRINT @pf;';

   EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
   ```
4. Please [avoid lazy shorthand like `DD`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). It takes an extra microsecond to type `DAY`, but the benefit is well worth it: it makes the code that much clearer and more self-documenting, and avoids fostering that shortcut for other dateparts, which can change the meaning and, therefore, the results (like `y` and `w`).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may not have properly escaped all quotes.

This:

```
SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + ...
```

...probably needs to become this:

```
SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''''''' + ...
```

And the same thing in a couple other places.

Answer (score 1):

You just have an extra end.

Either add a `begin ..end` or remove `end`

[image]

```
  declare @sql nvarchar(max)
  set @sql = 'DECLARE @DatePartitionFunction nvarchar(max) = N''CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION DatePartitionFunction (datetime) 
                                             AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('';
    DECLARE @incremental_date nvarchar(150);

    select @incremental_date = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),112)+'
    declare @counter int = 0;
    WHILE @counter < 3
    BEGIN
        SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),DATEADD(DD, @counter, @incremental_date),112) + '''' + N'', '';
        SET @counter += 1; 
    END

    SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),DATEADD(DD, @counter, @incremental_date),112)  + '''' + N'');'';
    print (@DatePartitionFunction);'

--print @sql
exec (@sql);
```

above outputs

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION DatePartitionFunction (datetime) 
                                             AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (20150923, 20150924, 20150925, 20150926);
```